# Создание волн на css

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание на волны, которые есть в background и как они четко проходят сквозь телефон.
Подскажите, телефон должен быть частью фона или отдельным элементом?
Можно ли нарисовать эти волны на css отдельно?

Comment: на самом деле эти волны не проходят через телефон , у телефона свой фон который в макете почему то свой , для того что бы фон у телефона отсуствовал надо его там делать прозрачным , в общем сохраните каждый слой отдельно

Comment: Спасибо! Я попробую